# Inspecting literal dimensions in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, web

I was using Firefox's web developer feature to inspect elements. I am curious to know if someone has a way of finding the exact dimensions, i.e. width and height in pixels, of a HTML element on a given page?

For example, right click right now on any element on this StackOverflow page that you're reading, click "Inspect" - is there a quick and dirty way of finding out how many pixels is being shown on your browser? Particularly the width, because often times the stylesheet denotes the height already.

Note:
My use case is to resize an image to exactly the width in pixels that it is being displayed, in addition to doing something like

```
    <img style="width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Inspect`, view `styles`, click the `computed` tab and uncheck `only user styles`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug)

It's and add-on for FF, activate it with Ctrl + F12, select the blue arrow and point to the element you want to inspect. You'll get where in the HTML that element is and on the right its styles. Select "layout" to the right of style and it'll tell you the exact dimensions